# How to apply different colours to each letter in a word in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, fill

I am looking for a method to fill multiple colours to different letters in a word without removing the outline / expanding the type?

Comment: do you want recolor the whole letters or part of letters?

Comment: Welcome to GD! I've edited your question to focus it more specifically as it was confusing. It could be interpreted in a few ways and I edited to one I think might be what you're asking but I might be wrong, and it's perfectly ok for you to edit it again to refocus towards what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** I might have misunderstood you: to apply different colours separately, I am not sure if there are any other way than selecting each and applying colour individually.

---

Select your text box, set both outline and fill to blank:

[image]

in the appearance panel, select `add fill`

[image]

Find a gradient you want to use, or create your own, and select that:

[image]

Oh, I forgot. Then select the gradient tool, and use that to "pull" the gradient to apply across the letters:

Answer (score 2):

As [Random O'Reilly mentioned in their answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/29436/13197) but didn't explain, you can highlight each letter while in 'type mode(?)' and choose the fill for each one separately without needing to expand it or use any destructive method.

[image: Changing the fill of a letter individually in Adobe Illustrator]

[image: Sample text]

Comment: Good answer, I got confused by the original post title that contained "rainbow" and therefore went to the conclusion of gradient. And btw, I am not a him, but a her ;)

Comment: What's the saying about assumptions again? ;) Sorry, lesson learnt; hopefully permanently.

Comment: No worries:) it is a common mistake around here