# Set each letter to a different colour based on a rule

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, character-styles, character

Is there a way in adobe illustrator to change all **same letters** to a specific colour, ideally based on a rule.

For example look at the image below:

[image]

I'd like to have a "rule" (something like character styles) where by applying it to any text it would change each letter colour as in the rule automatically. An ideally tool should also be case-insensitive and work with  different "letter features" such as fonts for example not just colours. In the example image above when the rule is applied, all the letters "A" are turned into green, the letters "C" into yellow and so on.

I tried to look around but I don't think it is possible to do it in illustrator. This answer [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/29444/146969) is a bit vague and not what I'd like to do.

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I'm aware there's nothing that can do that in Illustrator automatically, but maybe you could use GREP in InDesign.  Sorry I'm no expert using GREP but I should imagine it would be possible.

Comment: At a minimum this would need scripting for Illustrator.. but even then I don't know if it's possible. Character Styles, by nature, don't propagate across text and asking a script to OCR type to know what any particular glyph is seems highly unlikely. GREP seems viable as Billy mentioned, but I don't know if you can use GREP in AI scripts.

Comment: For what it's worth, if you have access to Microsoft Word, it's possible to apply formats (including font colours) to all instances of a particular character (or string of characters).  I don't use Illustrator, but if it is able to import (or cut & paste) text from Word whilst honouring the formatting, you might be able to achieve what you need.

Comment: I haven't used Illustrator for a while. Is it possible to copy formatted text into Illustrator from a web browser? If so, you could apply text colours quite easily with a simple bit of Javascript.

Comment: I just tried and copy pasting from microsoft word didn't do the trick. I was thinking maybe a small SVG script could do the job and maybe and open it in illustrator...?

Comment: @Ni-Ar [Is this any use?](https://jsfiddle.net/wjn781k6/)

Comment: You *could* do this in Indesign, which has GREP and character styles... export as PDF/EPS and open that in Illustrator. It should retain formatting.

Comment: Thanks @r3mainer very nice indeed, however if I copy paste into illustrator the coloured letters are gone.

Comment: @Ni-Ar Ah, that's a drag. I think you can paste formatted web content into MS Word, and you should be able to import Word documents into Illustrator. A bit tortuous, but it ought to work.

Comment: And I like auto color letter by letter depends on a specific image that contains some colors! The Automation Useful for typing special captions!